# is setting namespace to utf-8 any form of sql injection protection?

Tags: php, mysqli, utf-8, sql-injection

I am using a bit of borrowed code, and am concerned for its vulnerability to SQL injection...

```
// Set the default namespace to utf8
$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");
$userID = $_POST['userID'];
$json   = array();
if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM towns WHERE userID=".$userID)) {
while ($row=$result->fetch_assoc()) {
    $json[]=array(
        'townID'=>$row['townID'],
        'townName'=>$row['townName']
    );
}
}
$result->close(); 
header("Content-Type: text/json");
echo json_encode(array( 'towns'  =>   $json ));
```

Question 1: Does `$mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'");` have any form of sql injection assistance?
Question 2: Should I be using some form of real_escape_string?

If I need to use real_escape_string, should I set the var like this:

```
$userID = $_POST['userID'];
$userID = $mysqli->real_escape_string($userID);
```

Then, I can use it just like I currently am in my query?

Thanks

Comment: `real_escape_string()` takes the charset into account, but changing the charset itself doesn't offer any specific protection.  Yes - use `$mysql->real_escape_string($userID)` exactly as you have asked.

Comment: @Michael and one who upvoted. You are wrong.

Comment: Use $mysqli->set_charset('utf8') instead of $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'") for preventing SQL injection. See http://www.php.net/manual/en/mysqlinfo.concepts.charset.php for the details.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> Question 1: Does $mysqli->query("SET NAMES 'utf8'"); have any form of sql injection assistance?

Worded this way - definitely NO.
But see the note at the bottom.

> Question 2: Should I be using some form of real_escape_string?

You are asking out of delusion that escaping has something to do with injections, while it is not. So, let's rephrase your question:

> Question 2a: Should I be take some precautions against SQL injections?

Yes.
You have three choices.

1. Since $userID being a number, you may cast it to that type explicitly, `$userID = intval($_POST['userID'];)`
2. Mysql (when not in the STRICT MODE) let you send the number as a string. Strings has to be formatted according to these 2 simple rules, as it shown in the Rob's answer:

   - it has to be delimited by single quotes
   - these quotes have to be escaped.
3. You can use prepared statements. To use such a fashionable way of running sql queries you have to use `prepare()` + `execute()` methods instead of `query()` and bind your variable using `bind_param()`.

A note regarding the title question.

> is setting namespace to utf-8 any form of sql injection protection?

**Yes,** in a way.
In some, extremely rare circumstances, it is.
For some rare encodings `real_escape_string` family function may fail proper delimiter escaping. To avoid that, one have to set up the client encoding using `set_charset` family function, `mysqli->set_charset()` in your case.

Answer (score 2):

Escaping `$userId` is not sufficient.

You also have to quote the value in the query, or filter `$userId` (to only allow digits).

```
if($result = $mysqli->query("SELECT * FROM towns WHERE userID='".$userID."'")) {
//                                                            ^         ^^^^
```

Comment: Also, do not use the `*` wildcard, but specify the column names.